# Pass Hidden parameters using response.sendRedirect()

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post, url-parameters

How would I pass hidden parameters? I want to call a page (test.jsp) but also pass 2 hidden parameters like a post.

```
response.sendRedirect("/content/test.jsp");
```

Comment: @informatik01 my answer covers what you covered in yours except that mine adds the view part of removing session attribute using JSTL.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry dude, I'll delete my comment to make sure you're OK. By the way, that answer was posted about 5 month ago )

Comment: @informatik01 didn't know about your post, but looks like we both know (among other people around the world) how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[TheNewIdiot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001209/1065197) successfully explains the problem and the reason why you can't send attributes in request through a redirect. Possible solutions:

1. Using forwarding. This will enable that request attributes could be passed to the view and you can use them in form of [`ServletRequest#getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) or by using [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). Short example (reusing TheNewIdiot's answer] code).

   **Controller (your servlet)**

   ```
   request.setAttribute("message", "Hello world");
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
   ```

   **View (your JSP)**

   Using scriptlets:

   ```
   <%
       out.println(request.getAttribute("message"));
   %>
   ```

   This is just for **information purposes**. Scriptlets usage **must be avoided**: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197). Below there is the example using EL and JSTL.

   ```
   <c:out value="${message}" />
   ```
2. If you can't use forwarding (because you don't like it or you don't feel it that way or because you must use a redirect) then an option would be saving a message as a session attribute, then redirect to your view, recover the session attribute in your view and **remove it** from session. Remember to always have your user session with only relevant data. Code example

   **Controller**

   ```
   //if request is not from HttpServletRequest, you should do a typecast before
   HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   //save message in session
   session.setAttribute("helloWorld", "Hello world");
   response.sendRedirect("/content/test.jsp");
   ```

   **View**

   Again, showing this using scriptlets and then EL + JSTL:

   ```
   <%
       out.println(session.getAttribute("message"));
       session.removeAttribute("message");
   %>

   <c:out value="${sessionScope.message}" />
   <c:remove var="message" scope="session" />
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you cannot send a POST request using [sendRedirect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) method. You can use [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) to [forward()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) requests with parameters within the same web application, same context.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext().getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

The HTTP spec states that all redirects must be in the form of a GET (or HEAD). 
You can consider encrypting your query string parameters if security is an issue. 
Another way is you can POST to the target by having a hidden form with method POST and submitting it with javascript when the page is loaded.

Comment: @AshishAnand See my edited answer , you can use `RequestDispatcher` within same web app.

Comment: should it be getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(...) ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `session`, I successfully passed a parameter (`name`) from servlet #1 to servlet #2, using `response.sendRedirect` in servlet #1. Servlet #1 code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    ...
    request.getSession().setAttribute("name", name);
    response.sendRedirect("/todo.do");
```

In Servlet #2, you don't need to get `name` back. It's already connected to the session. You could do `String name = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("name");` ---but you don't need this.

If Servlet #2 calls a JSP, you can show `name` this way on the JSP webpage:

`<h1>Welcome ${name}</h1>`

Answer (score -2):

To send a variable value through URL in response.sendRedirect(). I have used it for one variable, you can also use it for two variable by proper concatenation.

String value="xyz";

response.sendRedirect("/content/test.jsp?var="+value);

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
out.println("<script>window.location.href = \"hoadon?OrderId=" + getIdOrder + "\"\n</script>>");
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.