# How to display username once user logins successfully?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I created a Registration form using HTML and add a sign In page also in HTML. I need to display the username on the top of the series of pages once i login. I have already know how to do that in PHP, but i want to know whether i can do it with JSP or not. If i can do it, how to do that.

Comment: Have you ever used EL with request attributes? If not, it's a good place to start.

Comment: And how did you that on php? and what are you trying to do so in jsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumming the user has been successfully validated and authenticated into the system in your servlet (or another controller), then just save the `User` object in session and then retrieve it where you need it. A basic example:

In your servlet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    User user = new UserService().login(username, password);
    if (user != null) {
        //success!
        //save the user data in session scope
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        //do your forward or redirect...
    }
    //do your forward or redirect to show error messages...
}
```

Then in your JSP code, you can access to `user` session attribute using [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), **never** scriptlets (more info on avoid scriptlets usage: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)).

```html
<div id="top">
    <!-- this assumes your User class has a username field with a valid getter -->
    Hello ${user.username}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. and also can you help me how to display a error message(not error page) if a user enters wrong login or password while signIn.

Comment: @sapan that should be handled in a new Q/A. Anyway, related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17001503/1065197