# Significance of return type in spring file download controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

What is the significance of return type in spring controllers which are used for download. Please consider the following use case:

```
public ModelAndView execute(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        //some code.
    } catch {
        //handle the exception and build a error model and view. This model and view
        //gives a lot of freedom for error handling in case of download fails on the
        //same page without change in URL(enabling refresh of the same page again 
        //and again)
        return modelAndView;
    }
    return null;
}
```

but generally I have seen controllers which has void return types which would look like the one below

```
    public void execute(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        //some code.
    } catch {
        //handle the exception but you cannot display the error with out leaving the same page. Error embedding is not possible without changing the URL.
    }
}
```

I have two question here:

a) Are their any disadvantages of one approach over other. I see first serves more use cases than second.

b)Is there any disadvantage of returning `null` instead of ModelAndView.

References:

[Downloading a file from spring controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers)

[Error handling by redirection in spring download file controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324092/error-handling-by-redirection-in-spring-download-file-controller)

Comment: How are you trying to put the file contents into the response? It's unusual in Spring MVC to handle the response object directly.

Comment: @chrylis Being new to spring, I followed the technique given in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673260/downloading-a-file-from-spring-controllers (which is also there in references). Given that it was highly upvoted,I never doubted it.

Comment: As I said, it's unusual, not necessarily wrong. Writing a complete file as the output response may be the most common case, but then, you don't return anything from your controller method because that controller is already managing the entire HTTP return.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam has the answer helped you? :)

Comment: @Yuri Forgot to mark as answer. Not sure why. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing bad as for marking method as `void`. You are handling download action via `HttpServletResponse`.
There are suggestions that `FileSystemResource` is cleaner but take into account that for e.g. there are cases that you need to forward your data to some other place in order to compose the report in the other place.

Also **Spring** lets you easily handle exceptions even when your return type in the controller is `void`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pdf-report/{id}.pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadPdfReport(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {

    //supposed logic here
    //if we are failing here then
    throw new UserFriendlyException("Cannot produce data");
}
```

Then `ControllerAdvice` plays its role:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(UserFriendlyException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleUserFriendlyException(UserFriendlyException ex) {
        //handle here your custom error page
    }
}
```

More info on that from the [Spring resources](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)