# create arraylist in servlet and show in jsp

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have an object that I want to store in ArrayList and then show it in jsp called "next", but I don't know how to display it.

this is my code:

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");

String age = request.getParameter("age");

User u = new User (name, age);

ArrayList<User> user= new ArrayList<User>();

user.add(u);
response.sendRedirect("next.jsp");
```

Comment: just google jsp demo

Comment: Where are you setting your object to access that in the jsp?You should first set in request or session based on your requirement and then you can display in jsp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001185/pass-hidden-parameters-using-response-sendredirect

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.dineshonjava.com/jsp-forward-vs-redirect/